# Got a Java process with about 4 GB memory consumption after just starting up macOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, launchd, java

I recently found there is a Java process with more than 4 GB memory in my MBP, and it respawned after I force quit it.

After restarting the computer and entering `safe mode`, the process does not appear in. And I removed all the *LoginItems* of my account and cleared the path `/Library/StartItems/`, and restart in normal mode. Then the problem still there: a java process appeared after about a minute when entering the system. And seems the process do nothing...

[image: activity monitor]

I have no idea where the process come from and how to totally remove it.

OS: High Sierra 10.13.2

Comment: Please could you check in the following folders for launchd jobs: `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, `~/Library/LaunchDaemons`. It is likely one of these jobs is responsible. Feel to edit and add the file names to your question.

Comment: Issue the command `sudo launchctl list | grep 458`  This will list the service associated with that process ID.  Note that the PID may change, so check activity monitor for the PID number before issuing the command.

Comment: @GrahamMiln thanks! Turns out it's the apache cassandra database daemon process. And it's in the ~/Library/LaunchAgents , added by `brew start cassandra`. I tried sometime ago and forgotten..

Comment: @Allan Thanks! Your solution works but seems have a small issue. When use `sudo`, the output only list process owned by root. Since the process is in my own account `~/Library/LanuchAgents`, I just use `launchctl list | grep xxx` without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Allan's solution in his comment

> Issue the command `sudo launchctl list | grep 458` This will list the service associated with that process ID. Note that the PID may change, so check activity monitor for the PID number before issuing the command.

worked very well (In this case as the rogue process was run as the current user this worked without "sudo" also).

For me also it is Cassandra which is consuming the memory.

Comment: Good to hear. To help others who find this answer, how did you stop or remove `cassandra`?

Comment: `brew services stop cassandra` worked for me.